# Visual Studio Property Grid: Accept an empty string for Int properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, propertygrid

I have a property grid with various value types including integers. Some of the int properties have the DefaultValueAttribute, specifying a default value of, e.g. -1.

If a user enters an empty string, Visual Studio complains that "Property value is not valid; '' cannot be converted to Int32". Is there anyway to interpret an empty string as a reverting to the default value?

We have a custom PropertyDescriptor implemented, but the SetValue() method is called *after* VS does the conversion to the object value type.

Comment: This is just a guess - I haven't tried it, and I haven't researched it.  Try making the property `int?`.

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work, but I need the property to be a regular (non-nullable) int...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a derived class of `Int32Converter` and attach it to your property. Override its `ConvertFrom` method to insert the behavior you want. Optimally you will use the DefaultAttribute set to the PropertyDescriptor to make it reusable.

Use the Reflector tool in case you want to see how `BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom` is done.

Comment: Hi @nicolas, the answer above is a little difficult to understand, do you have a sample code I can see please